# How to fill down foumula in the excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have used `Selection.Filldown` but it is taking only the first value. Please check my code below:

```
Sub tsautomation()
    '
    '    tsautomation Macro
    '
    Windows("Feeding document.xlsx").Activate
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Range("A1:AP1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Book3").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.Offset(1, 36).Select
    ActiveCell = Range("AJ2") * Range("Q2")
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
End Sub
```

It is not calculating automatically.

Comment: form which workbook are you trying to copy ? and from what cell ?

Comment: If you look at the definition of `FillDown`, that is what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @AJD Is it not the code for excel option Cntrl+D with formulas in the first cell?. Please let me know what is the code.

Comment: @ShahiRado I was trying to copy in book 3. I want to copy the formla (I.e. AJ2 & Q2) in column K. When I am doing that it is copying only the first result to all cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your code, carefully.  What are you trying to `FillDown`?  The line in question is `ActiveCell = Range("AJ2") * Range("Q2")` - this is not a formula, this is a value.  You can double-check this using a breakpoint, and looking at the values in the sheet.

To make this a *formula*, you would use `ActiveCell.Formula = "=AJ2*Q2"`

---

Also, please have a look at how to avoid using `ActiveCell`, `Select` or `Selection` unless absolutely necessary - it is a common way to find yourself experiencing "unexpected functionality".  For example:

```vb
Windows("Feeding document.xlsx").Activate
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Range("A1:AP1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Book3").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

can all become

```vb
Workbooks("Book3").Activate
With Worksheets("Feeding document.xlsx").ActiveSheet 'Or specify with Worksheets("SheetName")
    .Range(.Range("A1").End(xlDown), .Range("AJ1")).Copy Destination:=Selection 'Copy cells to Destination
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. I recorded a macro with my requirement and I found a line. Its works like magic.

Replace

ActiveCell = Range("AJ2") * Range("Q2")

With

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*RC[-20]"

Voila